OpenAI Whisper - Why and how Byte Pair Tokenizer can affect Transcription performance?
The Whisper Paper says it could be BPE (Byte Pair Encoding) that caused the poor WER performance for certain languages (HE, TE, ZH, KO) that are distant from the Indo-European languages.

3.4. Multi-lingual Speech Recognition




2.2. Model


How BPE trained on the non multiple languages (majority of them are seemingly Indo-European languages) can cause the performance degradation for non Indo-European languages?
Or how the differences between distributions of byte pairs of Indo European language words and phrase and those of non Indo European language can cause it?
